# Filter 2d array by Hashmap key and value

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, hashmap

I have a String[][] array and a HashMap<String, Integer>

```
String[][] array = {{"name1", "field1"}, {"name2", "field2"}, {"name3", "field1"}};
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();    
map.put("field1", Integer1);    
map.put("field2", Integer2);
```

From this i need to get an array of first Integer1 names + first Integer2 names if array[i][1] i.e. field equals map.getValue() i.e. field)

```
so for Integer1 = Integer2 = 1 
the answer is {name1, name2)
for Integer1 = 2, Integer2 = 1
the answer is {name1, name2, name3} 

Allways Integer1 <= rows with field1 Integer2 <= rows with field2
```

the only thing i could do is horrible tripple cycle which is not even properly working

the input is

```
n lines of strings
profession,number_of_employees_required

m lines of strings
name,profession,points1,points2
```

so i've decided to make a n-size HashMap<String, Integer>
and m*4-size String[][] array because i need it to be sorted is descending order via points1 and in ascending order via points2, so i've sorted the array[][] in needed way and now i need to get number_of_employees_required names from that array for each profession

i make input from .txt file which looks like this

```
2
developer,1
project,1
3
Bill,developer,6,100
John,developer,5,0
Steve,project,6,10
```

the answer is [Bill, Steve]

if input is

```
2
developer,2
project,1
3
Bill,developer,6,100
John,developer,5,0
Steve,project,6,10
```

the answer should be [Bill, John, Steve]

My code is:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    solution();
}

public static void solution() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("input.txt"));
    Map<String, AtomicInteger> hm = new HashMap<>();
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String line = sc.next();
        hm.put(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(",")),
                new AtomicInteger(Integer.parseInt(line.substring(line.indexOf(",") + 1))));
    }

    System.out.println(hm);

    int k = sc.nextInt();
    String[][] candidates = new String[k][4];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        candidates[i] = sc.next().split(",");
    }

    Arrays.sort(candidates, (o1, o2) -> {
        if (Integer.parseInt(o2[2]) == Integer.parseInt(o1[2])) {
            return Integer.parseInt(o1[3]) - Integer.parseInt(o2[3]);
        } else {
            return Integer.parseInt(o2[2]) - Integer.parseInt(o1[2]);
        }
    });
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(candidates));

    Set<String> res = new TreeSet<>();
    for (String[] candidate : candidates) {
        for(Map.Entry<String, AtomicInteger> entry : hm.entrySet()) {
            while (entry.getKey().equals(candidate[1]) && entry.getValue().intValue() > 0){
                    res.add(candidate[0]);
                    entry.getValue().decrementAndGet();
                }
            }
        }
    System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

It doesnt work when i make second input the answer is still [Bill, Steve]
I tried to use atomicIntegers to decrement HashMap value without hm.put(key, hm.get(key) - 1) thing

Comment: With this setup, you're using Strings as the keys in your map, yet you are querying the map via Integers. Any solution will look strange in this case. Are you able to modify the structures used in the problem? If your final goal is to get the names associated with the integers, you may as well use a single Map<Integer, List<String>>.

Comment: So every array is meant to store exactly two strings: *profession* and a *number of employee**? If so, can you change the sample data so that it would be clear that the second array element is a numeric string. At least like that: `String[][] array = {{"profession1", "10"}, {"profession2", "12"}}; `

Comment: Also can you provide an example of *unsorted/sorted* data?

Comment: And it's not clear how are you going to use the map. It would be **better** if you add your code attempt to the question, it doesn't matter it is not working correctly, failure is a part of the process. The code adds context to the question and also shows the effort applied to address the problem (which is **important** on *StackOverflow*).

Comment: Than you, i've added my code